# Pre-order Traversal on a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

For a binary search tree: 7 being the root 1 being the left child and 10 being the right child.

```
                                        7
                                      1   10
```

I have tried debugging this function to see how it works and i can't seem to understand one thing. After the function checks and sees that the left child and right child of 1 are both null it then moves on to node 10 and then checks to see whether the right child is null. Can someone explain the recursive pattern and why the method does not exit after initial check of node 1.

```
private void preOrderTraversal(Node node)
{       
    if(node == null) return; 
    System.out.println(node.data);
    preOrderTraversal(node.leftChild);
    preOrderTraversal(node.rightChild);
}
```

Comment: Don't bother, reuse [existing tools](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BinaryTreeTraverser.html)

Comment: @fge While existing tools will help you a lot, especially during producing applications, it is very educational to build your own stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The method `preOrderTraversal` (called with Node = 1 as an argument, i.e. with the left child) indeed exists, but then the control flow jumps back to the method who called it and that is again `preOrderTraversal` (called with Node = 7, the root, as an argument). So everything is fine.

Add these lines of tracking code and you'll
see what I mean and everything will become clear.

```
private void preOrderTraversal(Node node)
{
    System.out.println("Now in preOrderTraversal with " + 
                       (node==null ? "null." : node.data + "."));
    if(node == null) {
        System.out.println("Done. Exit 1 taken.");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(node.data);
    preOrderTraversal(node.leftChild);
    preOrderTraversal(node.rightChild);
    System.out.println("Done. Exit 2 taken.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. But how/why does it jump back to the method with the 7 node. Surely there is no call to the recursive function with the root being 7?

Comment: preOrderTraversal should be first called with node 7, then it'll print the data at 7, then the left child, then right. The call stack would be something like [7] (first call) [71] (left child) [71null] (left child's left child) [71null] (left child's right child), then continues execution of 71 and becomes [7 10], etc

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Recursion ,So lets start with a very basic example of `Calculating Factorial`

[image: Resursion]

Now as you see  a stack of method calls has been created ,the breaking point of this recursion is  `factorial(0) whose result is 1` which is the first value we get

Now at this point  the program will not exit , instead the **fifth Call**  return the result `(i.e. 0)` to the **fourth call** and so on , So that you can get the final result . And as soon as any method returns the result it got removed from the Stack of Recursive calls

Now Coming to your example of Traversing a tree

```
System.out.println(node.data); // prints 7 for first time
preOrderTraversal(node.leftChild); // Now the function is called with 7->left
preOrderTraversal(node.rightChild);// here is is called with 7->right
```

So the Same way stack of recursive call is created and the Program instead of exiting from `1` will return back to the method who calls it (i.e 7->left)
and now (7->right) will be executed

---

**Now  Recursion in layman terms**

> Someone in a movie theater asks you what row you're sitting in. You
>   don't want to count, so you ask the person in front of you what row
>   they are sitting in, knowing that you will respond one greater than
>   their answer. The person in front will ask the person in front of
>   them. This will keep happening until word reaches the front row, and
>   it is easy to respond: "I'm in row 1!" From there, the correct message
>   (incremented by one each row) will eventually make its way back to the
>   person who asked.